# MongoDB: $unset replaces with null?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have an array stored in my document:

```
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "createdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            },
            {
                    "accessdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            },
            {
                    "code" : "4ffa04fe06000000",
                    "updated" : 1375981038
            }
    ],
```

An update is performed to unset the property 'code':
`db.coll.update({'properties.code':'4ffa04fe06000000'},{'$unset':{'properties.$':1}});`

My result is this:

```
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "createdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            },
            {
                    "accessdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            },
            null
    ],
```

But I expect it to be this:

```
    "properties" : [
            {
                    "createdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            },
            {
                    "accessdate" : 1375981035,
                    "updated" : 1375981035
            }
    ],
```

What is a better way to unset, without that resulting null key?
Is '$pull' better?

Comment: `db.coll.update({},{'$pull':{'properties':{'code':'4ffa04fe06000000'}}});`

Easy enough.
This works.

Comment: Yes it will do that otherwise it would have to rebuld the array indexes which was chosen as a bad idea at the time

Answer (score 3):

To remove an array member you want to use $pull
See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: What if you've used it without pull? How do you get rid of the null?

Answer (score 0):

To remove an array member you want use $pull as mentioned here  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/ and 
if the array already contains null value then use

```
db.collection..update({criteria },{$pull:{"arrays.1":null}});
```